# Connecting Squirrel Client to DB2 Server over SSL Connection

Tags: db2, squirrel-sql

I am using Squirrel 3.5.0 client to connect to DB2 Database. Recently I have changed my DB2 to run on SSL instead of normal TCS/IP. Now I want Squirrel to connect to my DB2 server using SSL port. So I updated the port number in the connection string. Now I need to add the server certificate into the Squirrel client truststore so that it can trust the server connection but I don't know how to do it? Does anyone have any idea over it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case if anyone else is looking trying to accomplish the same stuff:

1. Find out the `JAVA_HOME` path.
2. Run the following command

   > keytool -importcert -file e:/certificateName.ext -keystore \jre\lib\security\cacerts
3. Open Squirrel, and modify the connection aliase. At the end of connection string append the following `:sslConnection=true;`
4. That's it, now you can connect with the database over SSL.

Answer (score 0):

I had success by specifying the following `javax.net.ssl` environment variables.

```shell
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=<pathto>\clientkeystore
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStoreType=JKS
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=<password>
```

This can be done in a couple of ways, I chose to add it to the `squirrel-sql.bat` / `squirrel-sql.sh` startup scripts:

e.g.

***squirrel-sql.bat***

```shell
...
start "SQuirreL SQL Client" /B "%LOCAL_JAVA%" -Xmx256m -Dsun.awt.nopixfmt=true -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=C:/ssl/clientkeystore -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStoreType=JKS -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=password -Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true -cp %SQUIRREL_CP% -splash:"%SQUIRREL_SQL_HOME%/icons/splash.jpg" net.sourceforge.squirrel_sql.client.Main %TMP_PARMS%
...
```

**Caveat:** this only allows one trustStore to be specified at a time. There are plenty of work arounds however: e.g.

1. Import multiple certs into your trustStore
2. Import a Root CA Certificate ([e.g.](https://s3.amazonaws.com/rds-downloads/rds-ca-2015-root.pem))
3. Have different start scripts

**See also:** https://sourceforge.net/p/squirrel-sql/mailman/message/25794656/

Answer (score 0):

What works for me is a URL that looks like this:

```
jdbc:db2://10.10.100.100:50010/DDEVD:sslConnection=true;sslTrustStoreLocation=C:/Data/db2trusttest/ts-02-new.jks;sslTrustStorePassword=changeit;
```

(mind the trailing semicolon)

Answer (score -1):

just edit your alias. Clicking on Properties. Then Driver Properties and choose Use driver properties for adding these properties:

sslConnection with true value.

sslTrustStoreLocation with the path of your jcekdb.jsk as value.

sslTrustStorePassword with your password as value.

Comment: i don't see any option to add properties?